# Does SQL Server 2012 supports transactional replication with updatable subscription?

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

On [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143550%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx), Microsoft states that:

> This topic describes the deprecated Replication features that are
>   **still available in SQL Server 2012**. These features are scheduled to be removed in a future release of SQL Server. Deprecated features
>   should not be used in new applications.
>
> Updatable subscriptions including immediate updating and queued
>   updating with snapshot and transactional publications.
>
> We recommend that you use peer-to-peer transactional replication
>   instead.

On [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/539d5bb0-b808-4d8c-baf4-cb6d32d2c595), Microsoft even teach you how to enable updatable subscriptions.

> To enable updating subscriptions
>
> On the Publication Type page of the New Publication Wizard, select
>   **Transactional publication with updatable subscriptions**.

However, I just can't find the replication type **Transactional publication with updatable subscriptions** on the publication type page in SQL Server 2012, see the image below:

[image]

Anyone can confirm, whether we have this feature in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the SPs instead of the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is supported but it is deprecated, which means it will be removed in a future release.  As Remus mentioned, you will need to use T-SQL to set it up as the *New Publication Wizard* no longer provides the option.